# Unable to install windows 8.1 on virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machines, proxmox, windows-8.1

How can I create a Windows 8.1 virtual machine using Proxmox?

I downloaded the [evaluation copy of Windows 8.1 Enterprise](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dn237247?download=dlm3&url=http://care.dlservice.microsoft.com/dl/download/B/9/9/B999286E-0A47-406D-8B3D-5B5AD7373A4A/9600.16384.WINBLUE_RTM.130821-1623_X64FRE_ENTERPRISE_EVAL_EN-US-IRM_CENA_X64FREE_EN-US_DV5.ISO). However when I boot up the virtual machine, it cycles between the two below screens.

Is there something that I need to configure or modify to make this work? Or is there a detailed log to view?

Windows 8.1 Logo

[image: Windows 8.1 Logo]

Boot Order Prompt

[image: Boot Order Prompt]